# Ruby Sequel Gem unable to look up tables with different owner

Tags: ruby, sequel-gem

I'm connecting to my company's database with the Sequel Gem using the odbc adaptor.

`DB = Sequel.odbc('myserver', :user => "USER1", :password => "1234")`

I connected fine but I was not able to get the dataset off of tables that belongs to other users.

When I connect to the database with Interactive SQL, I see the following tables.

```
USER1.TABLE1
USER1.TABLE2
USER1.TABLE3
USER2.TABLE4
USER2.TABLE5
```

When in interactive SQL.  I have complete right to do anything with all the tables since user1 is a superuser.  However, when I try to pull table4 or table5 with Sequel gem.

`dataset = DB[:TABLE4].all.count`

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb:23:in 'load'
       15: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.2.0/exe/irb:11:in '<top (required)>'
       14: from (irb):17
       13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:51:in 'all'
       12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:1006:in `_all'
       11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:51:in 'block in all'
       10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:152:in 'each'
        9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:90:in 'fetch_rows'
        8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:1089:in 'execute'
        7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:40:in 'execute'
        6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:270:in 'synchronize'
        5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:92:in 'hold'
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:42:in 'block in execute'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/database/logging.rb:38:in 'log_connection_yield'
        2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:42:in 'block (2 levels) in execute'
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:42:in 'run'
Sequel::DatabaseError (ODBC::Error: S0002 (-141) [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Table 'TABLE4' not found)
```

However when using the same code to pull TABLE1, 2 or 3 is fine tho.

`dataset = DB[:TABLE1].all.count`

=>999

Maybe because I'm not looking up table 4 or 5 correctly?  Or I have to somehow specify the owner of those table?  In Interactive SQL I have to do USER2.TABLE4 to identify the table.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a qualified identifier in Sequel, just as you need to in SQL:

```
dataset = DB[Sequel[:USER2][:TABLE4]].all.count
```

For more information, see:

- http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Qualifying+identifiers+-28column-2Ftable+names-29
- http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html#label-Identifiers

Comment: Just out of curiosity.  When I do     dataset = DB[Sequel[:USER2][:TABLE4]]    then dataset.count     I get the following error.  C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.29.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:42:in `run': ODBC::Error: 37000 (-131) [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'LIMIT' on line 1 (Sequel::DatabaseError).  I will have to do dataset.all.count to get the # of records. Thanks!

Comment: Use the Sequel sqlanywhere adapter and not the odbc adapter.  The Sequel odbc adapter does not have support for SQL Anywhere syntax.